# What exactly makes Option a monad in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads, option-type

I know what the monads are and how to use them. What I don't understand is **what** makes, let's say, `Option` a monad?

In Haskell a monad `Maybe` is a monad because it's instantiated from `Monad` class (which has at least 2 necessary functions `return` and `bind` that makes class `Monad`, indeed, a monad).

But in Scala we've got this:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable { ... }
trait Product extends Any with Equals { ... }
```

Nothing related to a monad.

If I create my own class in Scala, will it be a monad by default? Why not?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`Monad` is a concept, an abstract interface if you will, that simply defines a way of composing data.

`Option` supports composition via `flatMap`, and that's pretty much everything that is needed to wear the "monad badge".

From a theoretical point of view, it should also:

- support a `unit` operation (`return`, in Haskell terms) to create a monad out of a bare value, which in case of `Option` is the `Some` constructor
- respect the [monadic laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Monad_laws)

but this is not strictly enforced by Scala.

Monads in scala are a much looser concept that in Haskell, and the approach is more practical.
The only thing monads are relevant for, from a language perspective, is the ability of being used in a for-comprehension.

`flatMap` is a basic requirement, and you can **optionally** provide `map`, `withFilter` and `foreach`.

However, there's no such thing as strict conformance to a `Monad` typeclass, like in Haskell.

Here's an example: let's define our own monad.

```
class MyMonad[A](value: A) {
  def map[B](f: A => B) = new MyMonad(f(value))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => MyMonad[B]) = f(value)
  override def toString = value.toString
}
```

As you see, we're only implementing `map` and `flatMap` (well, and `toString` as a commodity).
Congratulations, we have a monad! Let's try it out:

```
scala> for {
  a <- new MyMonad(2)
  b <- new MyMonad(3)
} yield a + b
// res1: MyMonad[Int] = 5
```

Nice! We are not doing any filtering, so we don't need to implement `withFilter`. Also since we're yielding a value, we don't need `foreach` either. Basically you implement whatever you wish to support, without strict requirements. If you try to filter in a for-comprehension and you haven't implemented `withFilter`, you'll simply get a compile-time error.

Comment: so Option doesn't know that it itself is a monad? Unlike Maybe in Haskell.

Comment: precisely, in Scala everything that has a flatmap is considered a "monad" and it can be used in for-comprehensions (the equivalent of a do-block in haskell)

Comment: `Technically speaking, it must also support a unit operation (return, in Haskell terms) to create a monad out of a bare value, which in case of Option is its constructor.` --> how does Option reflect the fact that its constructor is "unit"?

Comment: it does not. That's only true from a theoretical standpoint, but it's not enforced or known by the language.

Comment: "so Option doesn't know that it itself is a monad? Unlike Maybe in Haskell." In Haskell `Monad` is just a class. Simply having a type class defined for Monad is not enough to really be a monad. The required functions must be properly defined. If I create a typeclass Monad for my own type `Foo` but screw up the implementation of `bind` for example, `Foo` is not a monad. It is perfectly possible to create the equivalent of the Monad class in Scala - I think it is actually done in Scalaz.

Comment: How does Scalaz implement unit without return-type polymorphism?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Scala doesn't enforce the existence of unit or the monad laws, and Haskell doesn't enforce the monad laws. In both languages it's therefore possible to have a non-monad treated as a monad, even if Scala's monads can be further from the definition.

Comment: In other words, a typeclass can enforce an interface, but it can't assure the correctness of the implementation.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson by emulating typeclasses using implicit parameters. Similar to this: https://gist.github.com/igstan/66e9bfd31d6ff03b233d.

Comment: Ah, nice! Can you write a Monad-generic value like Haskell's `forall m a . Monad m => m a`?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson my Haskell is a bit rusty, so I'm not sure if I got the quantifiers right, but I think this is the equivalent: `def quux[M[_], A](implicit m: Monad[M]): M[A]`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson yes you can, since scala supports higher-order kinds, so you can talk about `M[_]` and write generic methods that work on type constructors.

Comment: To respect the monad laws, shouldn't the `unit` operation be `Some()`? The `Option` constructor turns `null` into `None`, but `flatMap` doesn't reverse that.

Answer (score 13):

Anything that (partially) implements, through duck-typing, the [`FilterMonadic`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic) trait is considered to be a monad in Scala. This is different than how monads are represented in Haskell, or the [`Monad` typeclass in scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/7bfa306ee247818b3c1406bab99263180f466d94/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala). However, in order to benefit of the `for` comprehension syntactic sugar in Scala, an object has to expose some of the methods defined in the `FilterMonadic` trait.

Also, in Scala, the equivalent of the Haskell `return` function is the `yield` keyword used for producing values out of a `for` comprehension. The desugaring of `yield` is a call to the `map` method of the "monad".

Comment: but Option doesn't implement FilterMonadic. What do you mean by duck-typing in Scala? Duck-typing is about dynamically-typed languages.

Comment: It means that the compiler treats a for comprehension as a sort of macro and replaces it with calls to `flatMap`, `map`, `foreach` and/or `withFilter`. The typechecking is performed on this translation, not on the for comprehension. This is why I'm saying that it's duck-typing. Anything that looks like `FilterMonadic` will be accepted by a for comprehension.

Comment: Another formulation might be that for comprehensions are untyped. That is, before expansion.

Answer (score 9):

The way I'd put it is that there's an emerging distinction between monads as a **design pattern** vs. a **first-class abstraction**.  Haskell has the latter, in the form of the `Monad` type class.  But if you have a type that has (or can implement) the monadic operations and obeys the laws, that's a monad as well.

These days you can see monads as a design pattern in Java 8's libraries.  The `Optional` and `Stream` types in Java 8 come with a static `of` method that corresponds to Haskell `return`, and a `flatMap` method.  There is however no `Monad` type.

Somewhere in between you also have the "duck-typed" approach, as Ionuț G. Stan's answer calls out.  C# has this as well—LINQ syntax isn't tied to a specific type, but rather it can be used with any class that implements certain methods.

Comment: Actually, there *can't* be a `Monad` type in Java, since `Monad` is higher-kinded, but Java doesn't have higher-kinded parametric polymorphism.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: correct. See e.g. [this earlier answer of mine to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170493/when-are-higher-kinded-types-useful/21174565#21174565).

Comment: Another reason that Optional<T> shouldn't be considered as a true monad - if you read the Java 8 docs carefully, they state that Optional<T> should only be used as the return type of a method, not as the type of any piece of state. This is actually a fairly significant shortcoming, and unfortunately there's no obvious way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Scala, per se, does not provide the notion of a monad. You can express a monad as a typeclass but Scala also doesn't provide the notion of a typeclass. But Cats does. So you can create a Monad in Scala with the necessary boiler plate, e.g. traits and implicits cleverly used, or you can use cats which provides a monad trait out of the box. As a comparison, Haskel provides monads as part of the language. Regarding your specific question, an Option can be represented as a monad because it has a flatMap method and a unit method (wrapping a value in a Some or a Future, for example).